# How to htaccess for blog.website.com where it won't show blog.website.com/blog

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain for blog.website.com but when I got to blog.website.com/folder it shows blog.website.com/blog/folder/... "blog" is the directory where the subdomain points to.  How can I go to blog.website.com/folder without showing the blog link?  I have this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because you're entering `/folder` without trailing slash and Apache's `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash after requests that are for a real directories.

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```